# counting occurances of item in IEnumerable using linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I'm trying to find a clever way using linq to examine an IEnumerable and find the max occurrences of some element.

```
"aba".SomeLinqExpression(); // => 'a'
```

or

```
(new List<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1}).SomLinqExpression(); // => 1
```

Is there an easy built in way to do this I think I need an aggregation query but Aggregate and Count don't seem to do it. Maybe groupby?

**EDIT: Clarification**

I'm looking to get access to the most often seen value. I don't care how ties are handled.

if we have a string

```
"abcda" // note that there are 2 'a' characters.
```

Since 'a' is the most common thing in the sequence I want this operation to return 'a'

```
"abcda".SomeLinqExpression(); // returns 'a'
```

Comment: `Where` and `Count`? `GroupBy`, `OrderByDescending` and `First`? this question is not clear to me - please elaborate!

Comment: GroupBy, then OrderByDescending, then select the first Key.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel sorry for the duplicate I searched for something like that but didn't see it.

Comment: No worries. If you have used right keyword, you'd have got it. FYI this is my search term "c# find max occurrence of character in string" and first result is the duplicate link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I guess this will work:

```
"aqejqkndaasaamd".GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).First().Key
```